# Android Studio does not include global gradle.properties file?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-properties

I installed Android Studio (Arctic Fox / 2020.3.1 Patch 1) for Windows and added a `gradle.properties` file to my `username/.gradle` directory. However, when I open my android project, Android Studio only recognizes the `gradle.properties` file that's on project level. I tried adding various path variables such as `USER_HOME` and `GRADLE_USER_HOME` but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out I'm an idiot and didn't show hidden file endings... Therefore I didn't notice that my file was actually named `gradle.properties.txt` instead of `gradle.properties`